# Scrapy how to use a proxy pool

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy and tried to use a proxy pool by creating a customized DownloaderMiddleware. I am having some trouble and want to get some help here (I looked at the document from Scrapy website, but there is no code example)

My python code is:

```
import random

class ProxyRotator(object):
    proxy_pool = ['ip1...', 'ip2...', 'ip3...']

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://" + self.proxy_pool[random.randint(0, len(self.proxy_pool) - 1)] + ":80"
        return request
```

and in the settings.py, I added

```
 DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'pricecheck_crawler.ProxyMiddleware.ProxyRotator': 100,
 }
```

Right now the crawler doesn't get anything from the site. 
The log shows:

2016-02-17 11:27:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2016-02-17 11:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6051

2016-02-17 11:28:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2016-02-17 11:29:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: There is no error, but the crawler just not gets anything from the site.  For example, in the log:  2016-02-17 11:27:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-17 11:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6051
2016-02-17 11:28:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-17 11:29:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Comment: The proxy you're using is it `http` or `socks` ? Scrapy doesn't support socks.

Comment: Also, please don't change the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Remove the `return request` statement as it will return the request back to process_request and the `process_response` will never be called. Before this make sure you use only http or https proxies:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request.meta['proxy'] = self.proxy_pool[random.randint(0, len(self.proxy_pool) - 1)]
```

You can also change the settings to something like this:

```
'pricecheck_crawler.ProxyMiddleware.ProxyRotator': 100,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110
```

Also verify that `request.meta['proxy'] = "http://ip:port"`.

Comment: I still get the same result. The proxy is http.

Comment: Have you changed the settings ? Also check if the output of `self.proxy_pool[random.randint(0, len(self.proxy_pool) - 1)]` is someting like `http://ip:port`

Comment: so the proxy_pool is just a list of ip address I passed in, I make sure the final output looks like http: //ip:port.

Comment: I changed the setting, same thing. do i need to set http_proxy, things like that?

Comment: The proxy should have a port associated with it. change it as I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: yep, I changed that. I updated my code snippet in the description. Still the same outcome...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103761/discussion-between-rahul-and-user2628641).

Answer (score 0):

An additional direction might be using an external program, such as `proxifier`, in order to tunnel your bandwidth via a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scrapy_proxy_pool

Just add to your current code in settings.py

```
PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True
```